# emplace_back and VC++ frustration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, trying this both with the default compiler and the Nov CTP compiler, and the following below shows my problem:

```
struct doesCompile
{
    int mA, mB, mC, mD, mE;

    doesCompile(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) : mA(a), mB(b), mC(c), mD(d), mE(e)
    { 
    }
};

struct doesNotCompile
{
    int mA, mB, mC, mD, mE, mF;

    doesNotCompile(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) : mA(a), mB(b), mC(c), mD(d), mE(e), mF(f)
    { 
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<doesCompile> goodVec;
    goodVec.emplace_back(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    std::vector<doesNotCompile> badVec;
    badVec.emplace_back(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);  //  error C2660: 'std::vector<_Ty>::emplace_back' : function does not take 6 arguments

    return 0;
}
```

Why on earth does it seem emplace_back is capped at a maximum of 5 arguments?? They even say in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx that it would take an arbitary amount of arguments..

Is there any way around this, using VS2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VS2012 November CTP *compiler* supports variadic templates, but their *Standard Library* was not yet updated in that release. Should be fixed in VS2013RC. An upgrade is strongly recommended, because even the November CTP contained a lot of bugs. If not possible, use the macro mentioned by Konrad Rudolph.

Comment: VS2012 does not support variadic templates. VS2012 CTP supports variadic templates. Theoretically.

Answer (score 7):

It’s a restriction caused by the previous Visual C++ compiler architecture. Future versions of VC++ will lift that restriction and allow *true* variadic templates.

For the moment, you can statically raise the maximum limit of faux variadic templates by adding the following *before* any include into your code:

```
#define _VARIADIC_MAX 6
```

This will set the limit to 6 instead of 5 (up to a maximum possible value of 10) at the cost of decreased compilation speed.